# Why the listen() function call is not needed when use UDP socket?

Tags: sockets

I'm just curious about this question, can any one tell me?

Answer (score 19):

TCP is a streaming protocol between a server and clients.  The protocol is reliable and requires separate state for each server<>client stream.  The connect protocol, initiated with listen/accept, sets up this server<>client connection state.    UDP is a connectionless, unreliable datagram, (message) protocol, so no need to listen for new connections - datagrams can come in in any order from any source.

Answer (score 4):

It's because UDP is not connection oriented like TCP is, so there's no meaning in the listen/accept like there's for SOCK_STREAM. Try reading the paragraph "2.1. Two Types of Internet Sockets" in the [Beej guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) and the whole guide in general it is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember it correctly, there is not any Listen() method associated with Udp, instead you call receive(), which is the same as Listen() when using TCP, both will block the process until it receive packages. hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the kernel source code, `listen()` is mainly used for initializing `accept queue` and `syn queue`, which are useless when using UDP.

The call chain is `listen -> inet_listen -> inet_csk_listen_start -> reqsk_queue_alloc`